# when i run the program, the console jump a instruction and print "Nome: " 2times:

Tags: java, arrays

```
//inicio do programa
package calculodenotas;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class CalculoDeNotas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //DECLARAÇÃO DE VARIAVEIS
        int quantidadeAlunos;
        int[] qtdAlunos;
        int x;
        String[] nomeAlunos;

        //ATRIBUIÇÃO DE MEMORIA PARA OS ARRAYS
        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de alunos da sala de aula: ");
        quantidadeAlunos = input.nextInt();
        qtdAlunos = new int[quantidadeAlunos];
        nomeAlunos = new String [quantidadeAlunos];

        //LAÇOS DE REPETIÇÕES, CAPTURAR NOME DOS ALUNOS
        System.out.println("Digite o nome dos " + quantidadeAlunos + " Alunos");
            for(x=0; x<quantidadeAlunos; x++){
                System.out.println("Nome: ");
                nomeAlunos[x] = input.nextLine();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you translate your program? As-is, understanding its semantics for a non-native speaker is kind of hard. Where does it jump? Please create a [MCVE], with input, expected behaviour and observed behaviour.

Comment: Also, what inputs did you run your program with?